# SparkException: Task not serializable when using decision tree model in mapping function

Tags: scala, apache-spark, serialization

I'm currently trying to use the spark-shell to test the decision tree model and got a sparkexception about the serialization, the code and the error warning is below and I will put the description of my code at the bottom:

```
scala> import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._

scala> import org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext
import org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext

scala> import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.lit
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.lit

scala> import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.VectorAssembler
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.VectorAssembler

scala> import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vectors
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vectors

scala> import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.StandardScaler
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.StandardScaler

scala> import org.apache.spark.mllib.tree.DecisionTree
import org.apache.spark.mllib.tree.DecisionTree

scala> import org.apache.spark.mllib.tree.model.DecisionTreeModel
import org.apache.spark.mllib.tree.model.DecisionTreeModel

scala> import org.apache.spark.mllib.util.MLUtils
import org.apache.spark.mllib.util.MLUtils

scala> import org.apache.spark.mllib.regression.LabeledPoint
import org.apache.spark.mllib.regression.LabeledPoint

scala> val hiveCtx = new org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext(sc)
18/03/29 15:18:23 WARN SessionState: load mapred-default.xml, HIVE_CONF_DIR env not found!
18/03/29 15:18:23 WARN SessionState: load mapred-default.xml, HIVE_CONF_DIR env not found!
hiveCtx: org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext = org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext@3c2b7322

scala> val mobile_features = hiveCtx.sql("SELECT velocity_arith_avg,x_velocity,total_distance,ratio_distance,record_num,std_neighbor_angle,std_total_angle,std_abs_neighbor_angle,std_abs_total_angle,total_wait_time FROM yx_loc.tmp_junwang_mobile_features")
mobile_features: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [velocity_arith_avg: double, x_velocity: double, total_distance: double, ratio_distance: double, record_num: bigint, std_neighbor_angle: double, std_total_angle: double, std_abs_neighbor_angle: double, std_abs_total_angle: double, total_wait_time: double]

scala> val walk_features = hiveCtx.sql("SELECT velocity_arith_avg,x_velocity,total_distance,ratio_distance,record_num,std_neighbor_angle,std_total_angle,std_abs_neighbor_angle,std_abs_total_angle,total_wait_time FROM yx_loc.tmp_junwang_walk_features")
walk_features: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [velocity_arith_avg: double, x_velocity: double, total_distance: double, ratio_distance: double, record_num: bigint, std_neighbor_angle: double, std_total_angle: double, std_abs_neighbor_angle: double, std_abs_total_angle: double, total_wait_time: double]

scala> val train_features = hiveCtx.sql("SELECT velocity_arith_avg,x_velocity,total_distance,ratio_distance,record_num,std_neighbor_angle,std_total_angle,std_abs_neighbor_angle,std_abs_total_angle,total_wait_time FROM yx_loc.tmp_junwang_train_features")
train_features: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [velocity_arith_avg: double, x_velocity: double, total_distance: double, ratio_distance: double, record_num: bigint, std_neighbor_angle: double, std_total_angle: double, std_abs_neighbor_angle: double, std_abs_total_angle: double, total_wait_time: double]

scala> val df_mobile = mobile_features.withColumn("label", lit(2.0))
df_mobile: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [velocity_arith_avg: double, x_velocity: double, total_distance: double, ratio_distance: double, record_num: bigint, std_neighbor_angle: double, std_total_angle: double, std_abs_neighbor_angle: double, std_abs_total_angle: double, total_wait_time: double, label: double]

scala> val df_walk = walk_features.withColumn("label", lit(0.0))
df_walk: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [velocity_arith_avg: double, x_velocity: double, total_distance: double, ratio_distance: double, record_num: bigint, std_neighbor_angle: double, std_total_angle: double, std_abs_neighbor_angle: double, std_abs_total_angle: double, total_wait_time: double, label: double]

scala> val df_train = train_features.withColumn("label", lit(1.0))
df_train: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [velocity_arith_avg: double, x_velocity: double, total_distance: double, ratio_distance: double, record_num: bigint, std_neighbor_angle: double, std_total_angle: double, std_abs_neighbor_angle: double, std_abs_total_angle: double, total_wait_time: double, label: double]

scala> val df1 = df_mobile.unionAll(df_walk)
df1: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [velocity_arith_avg: double, x_velocity: double, total_distance: double, ratio_distance: double, record_num: bigint, std_neighbor_angle: double, std_total_angle: double, std_abs_neighbor_angle: double, std_abs_total_angle: double, total_wait_time: double, label: double]

scala> val df = df1.unionAll(df_train)
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [velocity_arith_avg: double, x_velocity: double, total_distance: double, ratio_distance: double, record_num: bigint, std_neighbor_angle: double, std_total_angle: double, std_abs_neighbor_angle: double, std_abs_total_angle: double, total_wait_time: double, label: double]

scala> val tmp_df = df.cache()
18/03/29 15:18:27 WARN SessionState: METASTORE_FILTER_HOOK will be ignored, since hive.security.authorization.manager is set to instance of HiveAuthorizerFactory.
tmp_df: df.type = [velocity_arith_avg: double, x_velocity: double, total_distance: double, ratio_distance: double, record_num: bigint, std_neighbor_angle: double, std_total_angle: double, std_abs_neighbor_angle: double, std_abs_total_angle: double, total_wait_time: double, label: double]

scala> val assembler = new VectorAssembler().setInputCols(Array("velocity_arith_avg","x_velocity","total_distance","ratio_distance","record_num","std_neighbor_angle","std_total_angle","std_abs_neighbor_angle","std_abs_total_angle","total_wait_time")).setOutputCol("features")
assembler: org.apache.spark.ml.feature.VectorAssembler = vecAssembler_6c704c649b5a

scala> val output = assembler.transform(tmp_df)
output: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [velocity_arith_avg: double, x_velocity: double, total_distance: double, ratio_distance: double, record_num: bigint, std_neighbor_angle: double, std_total_angle: double, std_abs_neighbor_angle: double, std_abs_total_angle: double, total_wait_time: double, label: double, features: vector]

scala> val scaler= new StandardScaler().setInputCol("features").setOutputCol("scaledFeatures").setWithStd(true).setWithMean(false)
scaler: org.apache.spark.ml.feature.StandardScaler = stdScal_0853b7f7dff4

scala> val scalerModel = scaler.fit(output)
scalerModel: org.apache.spark.ml.feature.StandardScalerModel = stdScal_0853b7f7dff4

scala> val scaledData = scalerModel.transform(output)
scaledData: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [velocity_arith_avg: double, x_velocity: double, total_distance: double, ratio_distance: double, record_num: bigint, std_neighbor_angle: double, std_total_angle: double, std_abs_neighbor_angle: double, std_abs_total_angle: double, total_wait_time: double, label: double, features: vector, scaledFeatures: vector]

scala> 

scala> val data_rdd = scaledData.rdd.map(row=>LabeledPoint(row.getAs[Double]("label"), row.getAs[org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector]("scaledFeatures")))
data_rdd: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[org.apache.spark.mllib.regression.LabeledPoint] = MapPartitionsRDD[22] at map at <console>:63

scala> val numClasses = 3
numClasses: Int = 3

scala> val impurity = "entropy"
impurity: String = entropy

scala> val maxDepth = 10
maxDepth: Int = 10

scala> val minInstancedPerNode = 10
minInstancedPerNode: Int = 10

scala> val categoricalFeaturesInfo = Map[Int, Int]()
categoricalFeaturesInfo: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,Int] = Map()

scala> val maxBins = 32
maxBins: Int = 32

scala> val model = DecisionTree.trainClassifier(data_rdd, numClasses, categoricalFeaturesInfo, impurity, maxDepth, maxBins)
model: org.apache.spark.mllib.tree.model.DecisionTreeModel = DecisionTreeModel classifier of depth 10 with 1591 nodes

scala> val labelAndPreds = data_rdd.map { row =>
     |     val prediction = model.predict(row.features)
     |     (row.label, prediction)
     | }
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable
        at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:304)
        at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:294)
        at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:122)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.clean(SparkContext.scala:2109)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$map$1.apply(RDD.scala:352)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$map$1.apply(RDD.scala:351)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:147)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:108)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:344)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.map(RDD.scala:351)
        at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:77)
        at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:85)
        at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:87)
        at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:89)
        at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:91)
        at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:93)
        at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:95)
        at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:97)
        at $iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:99)
        at $iwC.<init>(<console>:101)
        at <init>(<console>:103)
        at .<init>(<console>:107)
        at .<clinit>(<console>)
        at .<init>(<console>:7)
        at .<clinit>(<console>)
        at $print(<console>)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(SparkIMain.scala:1065)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$Request.loadAndRun(SparkIMain.scala:1340)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.loadAndRunReq$1(SparkIMain.scala:840)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:871)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:819)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.reallyInterpret$1(SparkILoop.scala:857)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.interpretStartingWith(SparkILoop.scala:902)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.reallyInterpret$1(SparkILoop.scala:875)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.interpretStartingWith(SparkILoop.scala:902)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.reallyInterpret$1(SparkILoop.scala:875)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.interpretStartingWith(SparkILoop.scala:902)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.reallyInterpret$1(SparkILoop.scala:875)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.interpretStartingWith(SparkILoop.scala:902)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.command(SparkILoop.scala:814)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.processLine$1(SparkILoop.scala:657)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.innerLoop$1(SparkILoop.scala:665)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$loop(SparkILoop.scala:670)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply$mcZ$sp(SparkILoop.scala:997)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:945)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:945)
        at scala.tools.nsc.util.ScalaClassLoader$.savingContextLoader(ScalaClassLoader.scala:135)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process(SparkILoop.scala:945)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.process(SparkILoop.scala:1059)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.main(Main.scala:31)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.Main.main(Main.scala)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:766)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:183)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:208)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:123)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.spark.sql.CarbonEnv
Serialization stack:
        - object not serializable (class: org.apache.spark.sql.CarbonEnv, value: org.apache.spark.sql.CarbonEnv@ff28a30)
        - writeObject data (class: scala.collection.mutable.HashMap)
        - object (class scala.collection.mutable.HashMap, Map(org.apache.spark.sql.CarbonEnv -> org.apache.spark.sql.CarbonEnv@ff28a30, org.apache.spark.sql.hbase.HBaseEnv -> org.apache.spark.sql.hbase.HBaseEnv@2933f654))
        - field (class: org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext, name: registeredEnv, type: class scala.collection.mutable.HashMap)
        - object (class org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext, org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext@3c2b7322)
        - field (class: $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC, name: hiveCtx, type: class org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext)
        - object (class $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC, $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC@7404ea32)
        - field (class: $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC, name: $iw, type: class $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC)
        - object (class $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC, $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC@6ec5e204)
        - field (class: $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC, name: $iw, type: class $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC)
        - object (class $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC, $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC@6ca9dba0)
        - field (class: $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC, name: $iw, type: class $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC)
        - object (class $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC, $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC@49d75bb0)
        - field (class: $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC, name: $iw, type: class $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC)
        - object (class $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC, $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC@31c00fe7)
        - field (class: $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC, name: $iw, type: class $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC)
        - object (class $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC, $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC@27dc80ff)
        - field (class: $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC, name: $iw, type: class $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC)
        - object (class $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC, $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC@63c512c6)
        - field (class: $iwC$$iwC$$iwC, name: $iw, type: class $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC)
        - object (class $iwC$$iwC$$iwC, $iwC$$iwC$$iwC@36d49430)
        - field (class: $iwC$$iwC, name: $iw, type: class $iwC$$iwC$$iwC)
        - object (class $iwC$$iwC, $iwC$$iwC@4eb0f3ed)
        - field (class: $iwC, name: $iw, type: class $iwC$$iwC)
        - object (class $iwC, $iwC@5c26544b)
        - field (class: $line31.$read, name: $iw, type: class $iwC)
        - object (class $line31.$read, $line31.$read@7569a46b)
        - field (class: $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC, name: $VAL168, type: class $line31.$read)
        - object (class $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC, $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC@50038523)
        - field (class: $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC, name: $outer, type: class $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC)
        - object (class $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC, $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC@2a105ba6)
        - field (class: $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$anonfun$1, name: $outer, type: class $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC)
        - object (class $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$anonfun$1, <function1>)
        at org.apache.spark.serializer.SerializationDebugger$.improveException(SerializationDebugger.scala:40)
        at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializationStream.writeObject(JavaSerializer.scala:46)
        at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.serialize(JavaSerializer.scala:100)
        at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:301)
        ... 63 more
```

In these codes, I extract three tables from the Hive and concatenate them together with a new column named `label`. After that, the new `sql.DataFrame` contains around 15 columns as features and 1 column as label.

Then, I used the `VectorAssembler` to merge all the features together in a new column named `features`. After that, I did a standard scaling for the vector of labeledpoint obtained from this dataframe and got a new dataframe called `scaledData` which has a new column named `scaledFeatures`. Then I generated the RDD vector of labeledpoint from the `scaledData` dataframe with the label and the scaled features.

Finally, this RDD vector was fed into the decision tree model and the shell prompts indicated that the model was trained successful. But when I decided to use this RDD vector and the trained model to generate the predicted labels with `map` function, it failed with the SparkException about the serialization.

Thus, I wondered someone could provide me some suggestions about it and also some explanation to the reason of the failure of my code. I'm the new to the spark and scala, so I'm still confused about the serialization method after reading the related documents. Thanks.

Other information:
The version of the spark here is 1.5.1.

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for the exception should be the anonymous function had the object that cannot be serialized. because before spark run task, it will check the function that user defined can be serialized, so it can be pass in the network

Comment: Thanks. I tried to serialize the decision tree model as well, but it still doesn't work. I guess the problem should still exists in something related to sqlContext, because when I used method of reading the hdfs file directly instead of reading from hive, there was no bugs about serialization any more. But still thanks a lot.